# How to read data from file and store into matrix

Tags: matlab, file

I have two txt files that are 1.txt and 2.txt. It stores data such as

1.txt:

```
P_e = [-0.1 0.71 0.88;-0.09 0.59 0.839;-0.08 0.55 0.816;-0.07 0.546 0.811;-0.06 0.46 0.769]
```

and data in 2.txt is

```
  P_e = [-0.1 0.5 0.6;-0.09 0.1 0.2;-0.08 0.3 0.4;-0.07 0 01;-0.06 0 0]
```

I want to cacluate sum of P_e variables column by column,except column 1 in 1.txt and 2.txt and store it into P_e_sum variable.

```
    -0.1    0.71+0.5    0.88+0.6
    -0.09   0.59+0.1    0.839+0.2
    -0.08   0.55+0.3    0.816+0.4
    -0.07   0.546+0     0.811+0
    -0.06   0.46+0      0.769+0
```

So the result is

```
Pe_sum=[ -0.1   1.21    1.48;
        -0.09   0.69    1.039;
        -0.08   0.85    1.216
        -0.07   0.546    0.811;
        -0.06   0.46    0.769]
```

Could you help me to implement it by matlab? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to be hard to read those in as text. But the contents of those text files are basically formatted as matlab scripts anyway. Rename them to `.m` then you can just do this:

```
run ('1.m')
p1 = P_e;  
run ('2.m')
p2 = P_e;

pSum = [p1(:, 1), (p1(:, 2:end) + p2(:, 2:end))];
```

Will do what you want.

As a side note, consider not naming these files just `1.txt` Matlab doesn't agree with numeric first file names.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I think you maybe change run('1.m') to run('1').

Comment: @user8264 no, matlab requires `.m` files to work with `run`. You will need to rename the `.txt` files to `.m` files.

Comment: Yes. I rename that files. But i check your script does not work if uses run('1.m'). It need to use run('1')